# Is there any way to see a list of tips in Words with Friends?

Tags: words-with-friends

In Words with Friends, they have tips in the News section. Is there any way to see previous tips (e.e an archive of these tips)?

Comment: Please consider providing a screen shot to help people answer your question.

Comment: Are you talking about the 'word of the day' section?

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen a gameplay tip in the news section, but their news blog is at http://www.zyngawithfriends.com/wp/category/blog/ and has an archive.